# IoT Hub routing using null value in json

Tags: routes, null, iot, azure-iot-hub

In the IoT Hub Message Routing, I would like to route message to particular Event Hub if a specific json value is not passed in the body, but the following statement is failing to evaluate.  Is this not possible with IoT Hub Routing query?

```
$body.productId = null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
IS_DEFINED($body.productId) = false OR $body.productId = null
```

Note, that the message must have the *contentType = application/json* and *contentEncoding = utf-8*

Comment: thanks, i will try the IS_DEFINED option. I have both the contentType and contentEncoding defined and can route off other fields, but i was having issues with the value being null

Comment: You can also just use `NOT IS_DEFINED($body.productId) OR $body.productId = null`